# Swift - exclude pod file from update

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods, podfile

I am using Swift 5.0 and I installed a pod where the code had to be updated manually - which I did.

Everytime when I run `pod install`, the changes I did (update to Swift 5.0) get overwritten and of course I want to avoid that.

What is the best solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

It will install pod without any repository update if you already have the library in the project, else will download

```
pod install --no-repo-update
```

If you want to update specific libraries you can use :

```
pod update [POD_NAME...]
```

If you don't want to update a specific pod you can fix the version number of your pods, so it won't be edited :

```
pod 'Alamofire', '= 2.8'
```

Comment: Hi @Menaim. But what about if I want to do an update for the other pod entries?

Comment: if you wanna update all pods, jus type: pod update

Comment: Hi @Menaim. I guess there is a missunderstanding. There is only one critical pod entry. Whenever I do a pod update, it should do it for all except the critical one. What I need is some kind of a pod ignore :)

Comment: @Melodias could you check the update on my answer

Comment: Thanks @Menaim :) But I still had to do some manual adjustments with the latest update. There won't be any updates anymore but still, whenever I do an update on the existing version, it overwrites all the changes I had to do to work with Swift 5.0